# Clarification notation in CLRS runtime analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, notation

I am learning algorithms from the clrs book. I am having trouble understanding the notation the book has placed.

The book wrote the following:

> $t_j$ denote the number of times the `while` loop test in line 5 is executed for that value of $j$."

So does that mean $t_2$ would represent the entire set time the while loop was hit when $j = 2$?

[image]

Comment: Ad downvoter: while the answer may be obvious to many, this is not a question that can be answered by looking into the book (more), because the notation in the book is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of iterations of the `while`-loop depends on `j` which changes during across iterations of the `for`-loop. Thus, the total runtime of lines 5-7 *must* depend on $j$, and the runtime of lines 6-7 *may* depend on $i$ (it does not here).

I can add nothing more over the quote you give; $t_2$ is the number of times line 5 is reached during the `for`-iteration with $j=2$, indeed.

Our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/48108/98) shows you how to obtain such formulae in a structured way. Try to follow the techniques from a blank start and you will see how this comes about.